# Filter Array based on a property in the array of its objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, filter

Given is following data structure

```
const list = [
  {
    title: 'Section One',
    data: [
      {
        title: 'Ay',
      },
      {
        title: 'Bx',
      },
      {
        title: 'By',
      },
      {
        title: 'Cx',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Section Two',
    data: [
      {
        title: 'Ay',
      },
      {
        title: 'Bx',
      },
      {
        title: 'By',
      },
      {
        title: 'Cx',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

What i want to do ist to filter this list based on title property in the data array of each object. 
An example would be to have the list where the title property of the childs starts with "B", so the list will look like that:

```
const filteredList = [
  {
    title: 'Section One',
    data: [
      {
        title: 'Bx',
      },
      {
        title: 'By',
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Section Two',
    data: [
      {
        title: 'Bx',
      },
      {
        title: 'By',
      }
    ],
  },
];
```

What i tried so far was something like that:

```
 const items = list.filter(item =>
      item.data.find(x => x.title.startsWith('A')),
    );
```

or

```
const filtered = list.filter(childList => {
  childList.data.filter(item => {
    if (item.title.startsWith('B')) {
      return item;
    }
    return childList;
  });
});
```

But i think i am missing a major point here, maybe some of you could give me a tip or hint what i am doing wrong

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're doing `.filter()` on `list`. This will either keep or remove your objects in `list`. However, in your case, you want to keep all objects in `list` and instead map them to a new object. To do this you can use `.map()`. This way you can map your objects in your `list` array to new objects which contain filtered `data` arrays. Here's an example of how you might do it:

```js
const list=[{title:"Section One",data:[{title:"Ay"},{title:"Bx"},{title:"By"},{title:"Cx"}]},{title:"Section Two",data:[{title:"Ay"},{title:"Bx"},{title:"By"},{title:"Cx"}]}];

const filterByTitle = (search, arr) => 
  arr.map(
    ({data, ...rest}) => ({
        ...rest, 
        data: data.filter(({title}) => title.startsWith(search))
    })
  );
console.log(filterByTitle('B', list));
```